# how to convert list to map by java8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

hello I'm new to the java world
I have a question about how to convert a list to a map by use tree metrics.

```
public class AdditionalMetrics implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3813944465194104658L;

    private Long id;
    private String masterId;
    private String nodeKey;
    private String nodeValue;
}
```

I want to convert `List<AdditionalMetrics>` to `Map<masterId, Map<nodeKey, nodeValue>`
and I search on the Internet it just shows

```
additionalMetrics.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(AdditionalMetrics::getMasterId,
                              AdditionalMetrics::getNodeValue)
```

Comment: by use three metrics.

Comment: I do not know how to use three metrics

Comment: I would avoid using nested maps. Instead I would create a `MetricsIdValueKey` with the attributes `masterId` and `nodeKey` and a `equals` and `hashCode` implementaion and then use it for a `Map<MetricsIdValueKey, String>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `toMap()` because you have many nodeKey/nodeValue pairs to map to a single masterId value (unless you use a merge function).

This is easier to do grouping by `masterId`:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = additionalMetrics.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                AdditionalMetrics::getMasterId,
                Collectors.toMap(AdditionalMetrics::getNodeKey, 
                        AdditionalMetrics::getNodeValue)));
```